Movie about finding the house where the first thanksgiving was celebrated
I set my DVR to record Modern Family this weekend on FoxLife and instead record this one. (yes my dvr is that good :( ). And because Modern Family only last one hour I miss the end of the movie.
This is about a blonde lawyer, her aunt die and she inheritance a house. When she and his boyfriend go to visit the house found a cute archaeologist picking up soil samples. The archaeologist after some studies said this maybe the house where the first Thanks Giving was celebrated.
She threat to sue him because is afraid to lose the house for historic propose. Even when sued he still is very friendly and get help from his lawyers parents to try solve things.
There is the annoying female reporter trying to seek a story and causing problems.
In the first scene she is in a meeting handling a case against an injured guy. She show pictures of the guy running behind a bus to show he is lying.
The movie was in color. Looks modern age. 2000 or Late 1990. In USA. So is in English.

@Paulie_D I didn't know any actors name but the archaeologist seem familiar. I guess is a recent release because was just show in Fox Life.

If you just DVRed it recently, what does the TV schedule from when you recorded it say it was? This should be very easy to check, if the DVR didn't track any identifying information to begin with.

@NapoleonWilson As I explain on the question. I try record two episodes of Modern Family but instead I got this one :$ . So not that easy.

But apparently it was on at the same time or around that time. Even if you messed up the channel, the window for what it could possibly be is really small.

@NapoleonWilson Sometimes my DVR isn't that accurate. So isn't just a small time shift. Is just wrong information. Third world problem :(

Possibly The Thanksgiving House, a TV movie from 2013. Lead actress is Emily Rose.
Plot synopsis:

When a Boston lawyer inherits a house in Plymouth from her late aunt, she has no idea she may have inherited a historical treasure. Her initial desire to sell the house is supported by her slick boyfriend, but she discovers that her house may be located on the site of the first Thanksgiving.

Here is the full movie:




Thanks Anne. Fun fact Emily Rose is also the voice of Elena Fisher in Uncharted game. I will finish watching during lunch <3.
